# Download torrent files using download manager

Tags: windows-7

Can I download torrent file with Internet download manager or direct download? Because when I download with it, then the speed is fast 24-28Kbps but with bittorent or utorrent is not downloaded.

Comment: ~~~~~~ yes ~~~~~~

Answer (score 1):

You can download the torrent file, you cannot download the contents of the torrent using a download manager like IDM. The torrent file holds metadata of the files to be downloaded, and regular download managers do not parse that and download the files.

Alternatively, a download manager like [FDM](http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/) can download files via BitTorrent